# elementTree is not opening and parsing my xml file

Tags: python, xml, argparse, elementtree

seems like `vehicles.write(cars_file)` and `vehicles = cars_Etree.parse(cars_file)` are having a problem with the file name:

```
import argparse
import xml.etree.ElementTree as cars_Etree

# elementTree not reading xml file properly

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument(
        dest='file_name',
        action='store',
        help='File name',
        metavar='FILE'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        'car_make', help='car name')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    with open(args.file_name, 'r') as cars_file:
        vehicles = cars_Etree.parse(cars_file)
        cars = vehicles.getroot()

        for make in cars.findall(args.car_make):
            name = make.get('name')
            if name != args.car_make:
                cars.remove(make)

        with open(args.file_name, 'w') as cars_file:
            vehicles.write(cars_file)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/benbitdiddle/PycharmProjects/VehicleFilter/FilterTest.py", line 23, in <module>
    vehicles = cars_Etree.parse(cars_file)
  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1184, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 596, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: syntax error: line 1, column 0
```

XML file, which I am trying to filter, is in the same project folder. I tried supplying the path with the file name and it still didn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cars>
    <make name="toyota">
        <model name="tacoma" />
        <model name="tundra" />
    </make>
    <make name="ford">
        <model name="escort" />
        <model name="taurus" />
    </make>
    <make name="chevy">
        <model name="silverado" />
        <model name="volt" />
    </make>
</cars>
```

Comment: For some reason, it creates a blank file and tries to parse it. My goal is to get it to overwrite the existing file.

Comment: At least for testing, use different filenames for the read and write.  If you suspect the problem is in `argparse`, print `args`.  Otherwise remove that part of the code and focus on the `ElementTree` call.  In other words, isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

works fine now but im still improving it. thank you

I made this modification in main.py:

```
path = "/Users/benbitdiddle/PycharmProjects/VehicleFilter/"
CF = CarFilter(path+args.file_name, args.car_make)
CF.filterCar()
```

And changed 'w' to wb' in CarFilter.py class file:

```
    with open(self.file_name, 'wb') as car_file:
        self.vehicles.write(car_file)
```

Comment: i isolated the problem, which almost became a project itself; but i learned